# How do I format a websocket request?

Tags: python, websocket, dogecoin-api

I'm trying to create an application in Python that powers a GPIO port when the balance of a Dogecoin address changes. I'm using the websocket API [here](https://dogechain.info/api/websocket) and [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/) websocket client.

My code looks like this:

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("wss://ws.dogechain.info/inv")
ws.send("op":"addr_sub", "addr":"dogecoin_address")
result =  ws.recv()
print (result)
ws.close()
```

It's obviously not the final code, but I just wanted to see if I'm even able to connect to the websocket and get any kind of response. When I run that code, it throws errors because of the colons in the request. I don't know what way I should format it that it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm guessing that the API wants JSON data. You can get that like so:

```
import json
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("wss://ws.dogechain.info/inv")
ws.send(json.dumps({"op":"addr_sub", "addr":"dogecoin_address"}))
result =  ws.recv()
print (result)
ws.close()
```

Comment: It worked! Now i have another problem though... I get an error saying something about SSL certificate verification failure. Maybe i'll try the ws:// instead of wss:// if that works... EDIT: Nope, now it jut freezes up!

Comment: If this solves your (asked) problem you should go ahead and accept it. It may be worthwhile asking another question (though you might want to re-read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what makes for a good question) when it comes to the SSL issue.

Comment: There's probably just some issue with the SSL certificates that you have installed... or maybe just *their* ssl cert :P